# Enable CORS preflight ASP.NET on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, cors, preflight

I have the binaries only for an ASP.NET application and I am trying to bring it up on my local. I am having some CORS issues while trying to bring it up.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/webapi/' from origin 
'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8089' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried several things including installing the CORS module on IIS from here https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

I have also tried to change my Web.Config to add the following. All I am trying to do is to just make it work to begin with so I want to allow all requests to pass through.

```
<system.webServer>
  <cors enabled="true">
    <add origin="*" allowed="true" />
    <add origin="http://*" allowed="true" />
  </cors>
```

but I still get the same error. The weird thing is, both the webapi and the ASP.NET client are on the same machine on different ports 8080 and 8089.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Hi there, no the problem has not been solved. I am still trying a few things to see how I can fix it.

Comment: Can't it be solved using Global file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to make sure you have successfully installed the cors module, then you need to add the following configuration in the web.config of the application:

```
 <system.webServer> 
   <cors enabled="true">
    <add origin="*" allowed="true" />
  </cors>
  </system.webServer>
```

This configuration node is under the configuration node.

If it is still not resolved, you can also solve the cross-domain problem by adding the following code to the Global file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")

            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }

        }
```