# How to set CORS access-control-allow-origin = * on site?

Tags: server, cors, iis-7

I have 2 servers.

1st have a cdn domain and on that, I am running font-awesome javascript and styles.
Now I want to access that scripts by using the cdn link on my other site. I tried but it shows the below error (the below URL's are examples)

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://cdn.xyz.com/fonts/Awesome/fa-regular-400.ttf'
> from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Appreciate your answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable CORS preflight ASP.NET on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112847/enable-cors-preflight-asp-net-on-iis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below steps to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in IIS:

1. Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager
2. Select the website you require and click on HTTP Response Headers.
3. In the  Custom HTTP Response Headers, click Add
4. Enter `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as the header name, Enter * as the header value.
5. Hit the OK button.
6. Now, you will find the following code in your web.config file.

   ```
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```